# Getting properties out from the Craft text object

Tags: richtext

I got this kind of object.

```
Craft\RichTextData Object
(
    [_pages:Craft\RichTextData:private] => 
    [_rawContent:Craft\RichTextData:private] => 
    Standard Rate:  Cancellation policy is 24 hours prior to 11.00am 
        on day of arrival.

    [content:protected] => 
    Standard Rate:  Cancellation policy is 24 hours prior to 11.00am 
        on day of arrival.

    [charset:protected] => UTF-8
 )
```

Can someone help me to get the text out from this ?

Answer (score 2):

This Object has a `__toString` function that executes `return $this->content;`. 
If you are in a template just do

```
{{ object }}
```

You can call the function `getParsedContent` as well

```
{{ object.getParsedContent() }}
```

In PHP

```
$text = $object->getParsedContent();
```